# How to select all elements between two nodes with XPath

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xpath

How I select everything (all possible nodes) between the 1st and second h2? There can be *n* nodes between them, and there can be *m* h2 tags.

The nodes aren't necessarily going to be contained in an HTML elment, so the selector can just grab them all.

```
<html>
 <h2>asdf</h2>
 <p>good stuff 1</p>
 <p>good stuff 2</p>
 <p>good <a href="#">asdf</a>stuff n...</p>
 <h2>qwer</h2>
 <p>test2</p>
 <h2>dfgh</h2>
 <p>test2</p>
</html>
```

I'm just getting my feet wet with XPath.  Please help my newbie question :)

Thanks so much!

Comment: why? it is well-formed at least

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One XPath expression that selects the wanted elements is**:

```
   /*/h2[1]
      /following-sibling::p
        [count(. | /*/h2[2]/preceding-sibling::p)
        =
         count(/*/h2[2]/preceding-sibling::p)
        ]
```

In general, in such cases one can use the Kayessian formula for set intersection:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

This XPath expression selects all the nodes that belong *both* to the nodesets `$ns1` and `$ns2`.

If you want to get all nodes between two given nodes $n1 and $n2, this is the intersection of two nodesets:  `$n1/following-sibling::node()` and `$n2/preceding-sibling::node()`.

Just substitute these expression into the Kayessian formula and you have the wanted XPath expression.

**In XPath 2.0**, of course, one would use the `<<` or `>>` operator, something like:

```
 /*/h2[1]/following-sibling::p[. << /*/h2[1]/]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error of my answer: I didn't read the sample XML well enough to realize what was going on.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the p with an asterisk to get everything between the h2s, even if they aren't in p tags? @DimitreNovatchev

Comment: @Hoppe, Yes, doing this will select all *elements* (not "everything" :)  ) between the two nodes.

Comment: Can you stop pestering OP's with comments such as "Was my answer useful to you?" on their questions. It's just noise and we're endlessly cleaning up flags because of them. If your answer is good it'll attract upvotes and be accepted. You should know this very well by now. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev: Can you please, stop interfering with my communication with people? Adding this to your deleting useful, upvoted answers and comments of appraisal, this makes you a clear antipattern of a good moderator.

Comment: Adding "Was my answer useful to you?" comments to questions are noise, we are simply asking you nicely again to stop doing that. They do not add value, and as an experienced and valued user of the site you should know this well by now. If everyone who posted an answer did the same we just have even more clutter. There are no exceptions, not even for you.

Comment: @Kev: If you really want to discuss this topic, and I think you badly need this, you know my email.

Comment: I do not discuss site policy via private email. In the interests of transparency to the community I would be happy to discuss this on [meta]. Please feel free to open a question on this topic if you think that you're being denied a right by being asked not to clutter the site with these types of comments under questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about xpath, but you have a tag C# 4.0 so the following code does the job:

```
XElement.Parse(xml)
                .Element("h2")
                .ElementsAfterSelf()
                .TakeWhile(n => n.Name != "h2")
                .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (Doesn't use XPath though)

```
  XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString));

  if (reader.ReadToDescendant("h2"))
  {
    reader.Skip();

    while (reader.Name != "h2")
    {        
      //Handle nodes
      reader.Read();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not a working example but it is almost there,

all you really need to do is fix the syntax errors and possibly fix the recursive items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:call-template name="tmpMatchNode">
      <xsl:with-param name="indx" select="0"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="self" select="node()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="tmpMatchNode" >
    <xsl:variable name="indx" />
    <xsl:variable name="self"/>

    <xsl:element name="name($self[index])">
      <xsl:value-of select="$self[$indx]"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$self[$indx+1]:name() != 'H2'">
        <xsl:call-template name="tmpMatchNode">
          <xsl:with-param name="indx" select="$indx +1"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="self" select="$self"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$self[$indx]:name() = 'H2'">
        <xsl:call-template name="tmpMatchNode">
          <xsl:with-param name="indx" select="$indx +1"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="self" select="$self"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:comment>DO NOTHING HERE AS WE HAVE NOTHING TO DO</xsl:comment>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```